# I received the error "ParseError thrown syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file"

Tags: wordpress, facebook, code-snippets

I received the error "ParseError thrown syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file" while trying to add a snippet to my wordpress website. I did not write this code. It was provided via Facebook to add Messenger to my website.

I look at other questions with the same error and tried to use some of the solutions but it did not work.

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
xfbml            : true,
version          : 'v5.0'
});
};

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
attribution=setup_tool
page_id="951491424998531"
theme_color="#BE99E8"
logged_in_greeting="Hey! Do you have any questions about our 
upcoming trips?"
logged_out_greeting="Hey! Do you have any questions about our 
upcoming trips?">
</div>
```

I expect the snippet to save and Facebook messenger to be on my website.

Comment: Where are you adding this snippet?

Comment: This is a code to add Facebook Messenger to my website.

Comment: Explain _where / how_ exactly you are adding this - in a WordPress site this could mean a lot of different things.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but it is really not the correct way. It should be done either from functions.php and hooked to footer or with a plugin specifically made for these.

```
echo "<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
xfbml            : true,
version          : 'v5.0'
});
};

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->";
echo '<div class="fb-customerchat"
attribution=setup_tool
page_id="951491424998531"
theme_color="#BE99E8"
logged_in_greeting="Hey! Do you have any questions about our 
upcoming trips?"
logged_out_greeting="Hey! Do you have any questions about our 
upcoming trips?">
</div>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added quotes and still receiving the same error.

Comment: What file is this in? Where are the <?php tags in the rest of the file?

Comment: I am adding this code using the Snippet plugin. The <?php tags are already in the plugin. This is the full code that Facebook provided me.

Comment: There is your problem. You cant add html code in there. In order for it to work with that plugin, you need to use echo, print_r etc. You'd be better off adding this in an html box. I edited my answer.